# Spring Cache not working as a compute property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I want to use a mechanism for create a one time compute function. I try to use Spring Caching. But it does not working. Please help me to solve this problem. My code like as below,

Gradle Dependency

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
```

Main Class of Spring Boot Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    public static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        // todo: Try to save response text and request body
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addResourceHandler("/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/")
                        .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).noTransform().mustRevalidate());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My Coputational property and Test method

```
public String test(){
        return hello();
    }


    @Cacheable("hello")
    public String hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "Hello";
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: when call 'hello' method first time. i want it's result add to cache. After call again 'hello' method, it cannot called, returns the result using cache. but my code hello method call again. i measure it using SOUT. sout call at the second time.

Comment: My english is not fluent. I apologize about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @Cacheable annotation caches the values when it is called from outside your @Bean so calling it from another method inside your bean will not work.

try something like

```
@Bean 
public class CachingBean {
    @Cacheable("hello")
    public String hello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "Hello";
    }
}

@Service
public class CallerService {

  @Autowired
  private CachingBean cachingBean;

  // Setters, constructors...

  public String test(){
        return cachingBean.hello();
  }
}
```

And then it should work.
That's because the @Cacheable annotation creates a proxy around the method call when it is injected as a Bean, so a direct call (to an instance created directly) or an internal call are not intercepted and the caching mechanism does not even see those calls.

I still sometimes forget about it and get biten by it at the beginning :).
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Method name and cache name should be equal ?

Comment: No, they don't need to be equal. It is the name of the "cache" where the results of the method will be stored.

You can use the same cache name in different methods, in case you generate results in different methods, and you can reference those methods if you need to update/clear the cache. (You can see how  \@CacheEvict, \@CachePut etc. work  in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial, for example)

In fact, it would be wise to not use the same name. Method names are usually actions/verbs, and for cache names nouns sound more appropriate.

Cheers